# Sobre as tabelas e Sequences que "vem" com o Oracle

Tags: oracle

Me ocorreu uma dúvida sobre a necessidade de manter as tabelas que vem "prontas" no `oracle`. Quando você cria qualquer conexão, ao olhar as tabelas é possível ver várias tabelas e `sequences`, para que servem em geral essas tabelas? Existe problema se eu excluir elas?

Exemplo dessas tabelas: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está acontecendo, é que no momento da instalação e configuração do banco de dados, você não criou um usuário/schema.

Você está "logado" como `SYSTEM`, o que não é o correto. Você deve criar um usuário e especificar os níveis de privilégios, entre outras coisas. Essas tabelas, fazem parte das estáticas e outras informações disponibilizadas pelo banco.

Aqui está um exemplo de como criar um usuário: http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-usuarios-e-liberando-privilegios-e-atribuicoes-no-oracle/26414